# I can't install and run Ubuntu 22.04 properly on Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

The problem is, Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't work properly on Virtualbox on my computer, even though it was running properly. And a new install didn't help.

I tried Ubuntu for the first time. At first, everything was fine, I was running Ubuntu with 2 GB of RAM and 30 GB of space on Virtualbox. I installed it, and had no problems with it. But after a few days, I started to have some struggles with loging in, whenever I tried to login, I had a black screen. Rebooting the machine helped for a while.

But I started having more troubles with running the machine now. Whenever I run the machine, it gets stuck on a black screen. I tried reinstalling again, changing the boot order, but they didn't help. Everytime I reinstalled it, I couldn't get further from the loading screen after the installation. I also tried reinstalling Virtualbox and dowloading the .iso file of Ubuntu 22.04 again. But that didn't help.

I used to get the error "Failed to send host log message." but it was working fine even though I get the error.
Also the message I get nearly everytime I try to run the machine now:

```
irp 21: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option
Disabling IRQ #21
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 2, error -62
```

Have you ever encountered with this problem, if yes, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: As far as I know minimum RAM requirement for Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop is 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure a functional VM with Ubuntu 22.04, I recommend configuring the following settings:

- Set RAM to a minimum of 4GB.
- Choose a graphics memory size of 128MB (default is 16MB), as illustrated below:
  [VirtualBox Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOWtZ.png)

This solution resolved the issue for me, and I encountered the same error as the OP.
I apologize for the German language in the screenshot; my VM is configured in German. On your end, "Anzeige" should be equivalent to "Display," and "Grafikspeicher" should be similar to "Graphics Memory."

Answer (score -1):

What I have found to work in the past is getting an older version of virtual box download. I was running it on an Acer Nitro with all default settings with the latest VB download and encountered problem after problem with the Ubuntu 22.04, but done some research and found that if you just switch to another (older) version of VB, you will be just fine. Hope this helps you!